# Json Object to a Multidimensional C# Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

**Is there a way to convert a Json Object to a Multidimensional C# Array?** I know it might be impractical but I can't be bothered to write classes and then *deserialize* the strings into them.

```
List<string> ohyeah = (List<string>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(g.CommToken);
```

**That returns an Invalid Cast exception!**

Example:

```
{"method":"getCommunicationToken","header":{"uuid":"9B39AAB0-49A6-AC7A-BA74-DE9DA66C62B7","clientRevision":"20100323.02","session":"c0d3e8b5d661f74c68ad72af17aeb5a1","client":"gslite"},"parameters":{"secretKey":"d9b687fa10c927f102cde9c085f9377f"}}
```

I need to get something like that :

```
j["method"]; //This will equal to getCommunicationToken
j["header"]["uuid"]; //This will equal to 9B39AAB0-49A6-AC7A-BA74-DE9DA66C62B7
```

**I literally need to parse the json object into an array.**

Comment: This is so f-ing ridiculous! There are so many f-ing libraries and none of them can do this simple-ass task ...

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Provide a sample of the json you want to work with.

Comment: FYI... A "List<string>" is not a multidimensional array.  I can't think of a built-in collection class that will let you access the data like that.  My only thought would be to convert it to an XML document, then use XPath to get the values you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parse and SelectToken methods of the JObject class do exactly what you want/need.
The Library can be found here: http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/37810

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"
{
    ""method"":""getCommunicationToken"",
    ""header"":
    {
        ""uuid"":""9B39AAB0-49A6-AC7A-BA74DE9DA66C62B7"",
        ""clientRevision"":""20100323.02"",
        ""session"":""c0d3e8b5d661f74c68ad72af17aeb5a1"",
        ""client"":""gslite""
    },
    ""parameters"":
    {
        ""secretKey"":""d9b687fa10c927f102cde9c085f9377f""
    }
}");

string method = (string)o.SelectToken("method");
// contains now 'getCommunicationToken'

string uuid = (string)o.SelectToken("header.uuid");
// contains now '9B39AAB0-49A6-AC7A-BA74DE9DA66C62B7'
```

By the way: This is not a multidimensional array:

```
j["header"]["uuid"];
```

You would have those indexers for example in a dictionary with dictionaries as values, like:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> j;
```

But here you would just have a "depth" of two indexes. If you want a datastructure with indexers in this "jagged array style", you would write a class like:

```
class JaggedDictionary{
    private Dictionary<string, string> leafs = 
            new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private Dictionary<string, JaggedDictionary> nodes = 
            new Dictionary<string, JaggedDictionary>();

    public object this[string str]
    {
        get
        {
            return nodes.Contains(str) ? nodes[str] : 
                   leafs.Contains(str) ? leafs[str] : null;
        }
        set
        {
            // if value is an instance of JaggedDictionary put it in 'nodes',
            // if it is a string put it in 'leafs'...
        }
    }
}
```